# What does "This is all" mean in this particular case?

Tags: meaning, expressions

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/424219/247356) says

> This is all in the context of the data-generating distribution (or underlying distribution of the data). You can check another answer I made for more details on this.

Remove the "in the context of ..." part, the first sentence is "This is all".

Neither [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=This%20is%20all) or [oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=This%20is%20all) gives a definition or explanation.

"this is all" is part of "this is all I know" or "this is all I have", what does "this is all" mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are parsing this right? IMO, it means

*This is all in the context of...* = *all of this is in the context of...*

where *all* is an adverb instead of a pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

In the link provided by you the *order of words* is wrong.

The correct statement would be “**This all is** in the context of ...”